# Referencing to the the OEIS

Tags: citing

I am writing my thesis and want to the the [OEIS](https://www.oeis.org).
As they say in their [wiki-page](https://oeis.org/wiki/Works_Citing_OEIS#Referencing_the_OEIS):
[image]
Now I created my "own" entry in the .bib-file and I get this:
[image]
Now I would like to add "Entry A080075" after "Proth numbers". How can I achieve that?

Here is my .bib-Entry:

```
@article{oeis080075,
    author={Eric W. Weisstein},
    title={Proth numbers},
    year={2024},
    url={https://oeis.org/A080075},
    urldate = {2024-03-19},
    journal={The on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences},
}
```

Comment: ... have you tried typing `Entry A088075` after `Proth numbers`?

Comment: Not quite on topic: You want `journal={{The} {On-Line} {Encyclopedia} of {Integer} {Sequences}}` so that you keep the capital letters as requested.